# Template and const types?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have these two functions:

```
template <typename T>
void Cache<T>::Setup(const std::vector<std::string> &v){
    Setup(v, v);
}

template <typename T>
void Cache<T>::Setup(const std::vector<std::string> &v, const std::vector<T> &values){
...
}
```

This should work if `T=std::string`, but it doesn't if `T= const std::string`.

How can I solve this? Especially because `vector<cost std::string>` isn't allowed, and even that was possible I would have problems if `T=std::string`.

Comment: [`std::remove_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv)?

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks for your comment. Could you please explain me how to use it?

Comment: The obvious would be `const std::vector<typename std::remove_const<T>::type> &values`. But you didn't provide enough details to explain what is the actual problem. (BTW, `vector<const std::string>` is allowed, it's just restricted).

Comment: @StoryTeller thanks, that solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Using SFINAE?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<false == std::is_same<T, T const>::value>::type
      foo (T & t)
 { std::cout << "not const T: " << t << std::endl; }

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<true == std::is_same<T, T const>::value>::type
      foo (T & t)
 { std::cout << "const T: " << t << std::endl; }

int main()
 {
   std::string        a {"abc"};
   std::string const  x {"xyz"};

   foo(a); // print not const T: abc (error if you delete the first foo())
   foo(x); // print const T: xyx (error if you delete the second foo())

   return 0;
 }
```